# Python csv.writer suppress white space

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv    
with open('bilaterale.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=' ',quotechar=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        spamwriter.writerow("0.0,1.0,0.992,0.984,0.976")
```

How can I suppress white space between numbers in the row ?

Answer (score 2):

Just write:
 `spamwriter.writerow([0.0,1.0,0.992,0.984,0.976])`

instead of: `spamwriter.writerow("0.0,1.0,0.992,0.984,0.976")`

Because `writerow` requires a list instead of a string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly write comma separated string in file object without csv module :

```
with open('bilaterale.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.writelines("0.0,1.0,0.992,0.984,0.976")
```